# Can I use HTTP::Server::Simple as a download http server?

Tags: perl, webserver, download

I need to setup a download HTTP server, I do not want install Apache.

Can I use [HTTP::Server::Simple](https://www.metacpan.org/module/HTTP%3a%3aServer%3a%3aSimple) as a download http server? Could you please give me some sample code?

Or is there other CPAN modules can help me to setup a download HTTP server quickly and simply?

```
sub download {
 my $cgi  = shift;   # CGI.pm object
 return if !ref $cgi;

 my $file = $cgi->param('file'); #file=test.tar.gz
 $file="/var/download/$file";    #file=/var/download/test.tar.gz 

 # send this file
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to install Apache (or nginx or other)? A "download http server" as you call it is a very complicated proposition, once you take Authentication, Authorization, Filesystem-related errors, Webroot, Directory-traversal, Unicode-mapping, etc into account. I would only really recommend implementing one yourself in really extreme circumstances.

Comment: Additionally, you wouldn't want to, as it doesn't thread/fork so will not be able to service concurrent requests.

Comment: It is just for temp use, for a friend. I do not care authentication and so on...

Comment: Sure then, you just have to read the files using `open`, `binmode`, `sysread`, etc, then print the contents to the client.

Comment: … with the correct content-type.

Answer (score 4):

The same as mugen kenichi's answer with Plack:

```
plackup -MPlack::App::Directory -e'Plack::App::Directory->new({ root => "." })->to_app'
```

This already takes care of the things David-SkyMesh commented on, and it is very easy to mix in Authn/Authz from the command-line. A robust pre-forking server suitable for facing the Internet can be switched in by adding `-s Starman`.

Comment: I like it. The only drawback: you have to install the module first.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [App::HTTPThis](https://metacpan.org/module/http_this).  After installing:

```
http_this dir_name
```

Probably doesn't get much easier than that. In fact, if you're already in the directory you wan to export, you can skip the dir_name argument.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments this is no trivial problem. However, if i need a quick and simple server to provide files I usualy do

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

in the directory I want to serve. It starts a webserver at `0.0.0.0:8000` and you can point your browser there to download the files.

I do not know if a similar one line solution exists for perl but I guess it does not get any more simple than that.

Comment: Ah well, if the downvoter would kindly leave a comment please. I hope it is not narromindedness because I answered a `perl` tagged question with a python line?